# Change Of Variable In An Integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

***1.***

Let $g$ be a function that is defined on $[\alpha ,\beta ]\sqsubset \mathbb{R} $ and  integrable on $[\alpha ,\beta ]$.For a fixed point $c\in [\alpha ,\beta ],$ we use $g$ to construct the new function:$$G(x)=\int_{c}^{x}g(t)dt,x\in[\alpha ,\beta ].$$
We can easliy verify that $G(x)$ is continuous on $[\alpha ,\beta ].$

***2.***

Let $f$ be a function that is integrable  on the closed interval $G([\alpha,\beta]);G(\alpha)=a,G(\beta)=b.$

***Proof:*** $f(G(t))g(t)$ is integrable on $[\alpha,\beta]$ and $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\int_{\alpha }^{\beta }f(G(t))g(t)dt.$

---

If  function $f(x)$ is a continuous on $G([\alpha,\beta])$,we can use some propostions for **Change Of Variable In An Integral** to get the answer.But if function $f(x)$ is a integrable on $G([\alpha,\beta])$,how can I deal with it ? I want directly applying the **Definition of the Riemann Integral**,I tried, but failed .

Any of your help will be appreciated!

Comment: Have a look here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.5938v1.pdf

Comment: @RRL：Thanks a lot ! but I can not download the related  paper on Kestelman’s Theorem and Davies’ elementary proof.If it is convenient to you,please give me some articles about this.thanks!

Comment: Your question made me curious as I had not thought about this before.  The Kestelman paper is referenced in Mathematical Analysis by Apostol, but I can't find a free download either.  I believe that proof requires $G' = g$ everywhere which is the case if $g$ is continuous.  The weaker assumption that $f$ is integrable but not necessarily continuous is made.  A weaker condition on $g$ is probably viable.  Ill keep looking - but I think those are the basic references.

Comment: @RRL：Thank you all the same